# Is there a way to combine rows in a Pandas DataFrame, given the row index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I am looking to combine row 2 with row 0, so that the unit of the row is part of the column header and not following the data point. The data comes from a .csv file in this format, but it would be much easier to work with if the unit was in the header. The unit is not always "mi/h" and can change in any given reference file. Sections like these have been extracted from larger .csv files containing many differently formatted tables. My end goal is to export each section individually into a its own .csv file. This is already working but I'm hoping to adjust the data, as described above, and then continue with exporting it to its own .csv file.

```
0 Avg Wind Speed       Gust Speed           Min Wind Speed     
1                 5.26                10.74                 1.34
2                 mi/h                 mi/h                 mi/h
```

Ideally, the output would look like this:

```
0 Avg Wind Speed (mi/h)       Gust Speed (mi/h)           Min Wind Speed (mi/h)     
1                 5.26                10.74                 1.34
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome if there is another unit like km/h ?

Comment: does your dataframe always contain two rows only?

Comment: @AnimeshMukherkjee , The expected outcome would be that whatever unit is in row 2 would be merged with the column header. So, "Gust Speed (km/h)".

Comment: No i mean if there is another unit in Avg Wind Speed itself..

Comment: @deadshot Yes, this DataFrame will always only have one value for each column and will always be followed by a unit

Comment: @AnimeshMukherkjee regardless of what the actual unit is, it will be placed in row 2, so whether or not it is (mi/h) or (km/h) it would, ideally, be added to the string "Avg Wind Speed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.columns=[c+"("+str(df.loc[2,c])+")" for c in df.columns]
```

Renames all the columns by adding the value(converted to string) of the second row and respective column.

```
df.loc[0,:]=[str(df.loc[0,c])+str(df.loc[2,c]) for c in df.columns ]
```

This solution edits the first row not columns, not sure which one you want.

Comment: @BorutFlis This solution worked for me, I added in dropping the row that initially contained the units - for some reason the units now have a bunch of spaces between them and the column header is output like this `Avg Wind Speed      (mi/h)`

Answer (score 1):

## Create a df header from row 0 and 2

```py
import pandas as pd

# given your sample data
data = {0: ['Avg Wind Speed', '5.26', 'mi/h'], 
        1: ['Gust Speed', '10.74', 'mi/h'],
        2: ['Min Wind Speed', '1.34', 'mi/h']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                0           1               2
0  Avg Wind Speed  Gust Speed  Min Wind Speed
1            5.26       10.74            1.34
2            mi/h        mi/h            mi/h

# create the new header from row 0 and 2
header = (df.iloc[0, :] + ' ('+ df.iloc[2, :] + ')').to_list()

# if there can be whitespace or floats, use the following line for header
header = (df.iloc[0, :].astype(str).str.strip() + ' ('+ df.iloc[2, :].astype(str).str.strip() + ')').to_list()

['Avg Wind Speed (mi/h)', 'Gust Speed (mi/h)', 'Min Wind Speed (mi/h)']

# set as header
df.columns = header

# delete row 0 and 2
df = df.drop(labels=[0, 2])

# final df
  Avg Wind Speed (mi/h) Gust Speed (mi/h) Min Wind Speed (mi/h)
1                  5.26             10.74                  1.34
```

## Write a new row 0

```py
# overwrite row 0
df.iloc[0] = header

# delete row 2
df = df.drop(labels=[2])

# final df
                       0                  1                      2
0  Avg Wind Speed (mi/h)  Gust Speed (mi/h)  Min Wind Speed (mi/h)
1                   5.26              10.74                   1.34
```

### If the header is being updated instead of row0 and row2

```py
data = {'Avg Wind Speed': ['5.26', 'mi/h'],
        'Gust Speed': ['10.74', 'mi/h'],
        'Min Wind Speed': ['1.34', 'mi/h']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  Avg Wind Speed Gust Speed Min Wind Speed
0           5.26      10.74           1.34
1           mi/h       mi/h           mi/h

# get values from row 1
row1 = df.iloc[1].tolist()

# update the column headers
df.columns = [f'{c} ({row1[i]})' for i, c in enumerate(df.columns)]

# drop row 1
df = df.drop(labels=[1])

# final df
  Avg Wind Speed (mi/h) Gust Speed (mi/h) Min Wind Speed (mi/h)
0                  5.26             10.74                  1.34
```